# Calculating Zoom from DPI and size to get fullscreen

Tags: zooming, pixel, dpi, poppler

In Poppler, PDF files are rendered as images, 
I'm trying to determine the suitable zoom ratio to be able to render an image that can fit the full screen.

I have all parameter but I don't know why the result is always wrong.

```
myDPIx = 96

screenX = 1366px
screenY = 768px

imageX = 720px
imageY = 720px

zoomX = screenX/imageX
zoomY = screenY/imageY

newDPIx = myDPIx * zoomX
newDPIy = myDPIy * zoomY
```

let's assume that we have a `render()` function, it will be called as follow :

```
new_image = render(image, newDPIx, newDPIy)
```

Unfourtunately, the rendered image is too big, which means that my calculations are wrong ?

```
newImageX = 1840 
newImageY = 1045
```

which is about **2.5** times bigger !

PS: if I set a zoom as `1.4` I get a suitable zoom, but I try to make this generic for all screen resolutions.
Am I missing something ?